# Navigation on Main Form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am Creating an app with C#. I have a ListView on the Main Form(FormM) which lists all the record, i can select on record and edit it in the new form(FormC). Now I want to have a Navigator on the Main Form. Suppose that the FormC is open and showing a record for edit. in That case i want that if i click the navigate button on the Main Form, the value on the FormC changes according the next or previous move of navigation.
the Navigation buttons is in the FormC in any samples that i found in internet. but i want those be separated.

any sample or idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **FormM**, make the **listview** a static member, to do this, go to **FormM.Designer.cs**, locate the declaration of listview and change it to **public static** type from **private** type. After you do this, plenty of errors will be reported in the same file. To fix those, replace all **this.listview** with *only* **listview**.

The above configuration will make your **listview** accessible from any other form. To access the listview from FormC, user **FormM.listview**.

Similarly change the Text box/area from FormC to public static. This will make the **textbox** accessible from FormM.

When you press next and previous buttons, change the selection controls between items and in the SelectedItemChanged action function, put the code to send the selected item to FormC's text box.

**Eg: FormC.textbox1.text = {your code to fetch the selected item}**